# Rails4 images in mailer (layout and body)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded to Rails4 and images in my emails broke.

What is especially surprising to me is that I can't find any doc on how to fix it on the web. I'm guessing I'm not the first one adding some image in a mailer with Rails4, am I?

Here's what's in `development.rb`:

```
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] }
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]
```

And I'm calling in `layout.html.haml`:

```
= image_tag 'facebook.png', style: 'margin: 10px;', alt: 'Facebook'
```

But it doesn't set any url at all.

I also tried with:

```
= image_tag asset_url('facebook.png'), style: 'margin: 10px;', alt: 'Facebook'
```

but I get a `undefined method 'protocol' for nil:NilClass` error.

Could someone summarize how all those `default_url` options are used and should be set once for all?

Thanks

Comment: Try to set `asset_host` options `config.action_mailer.asset_host = "http://localhost:3000"` or `protocol` in `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'somehost', protocol: 'http'}`